# express router delete - 404 not found

Tags: express, ejs

I am working on a sample app using express. Simple CRUD, a student has many dishes.

I am trying to delete a `dish` from a `student`, and when hitting the `delete` route, I keep getting a `404 not found` even though my code looks correct to me. Here's my current set up

**routes**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var DishesController = require('../controllers/dishesController');

router.delete('/:student_id/dishes/:dish_id', DishesController.delete);
```

**controller**

```
var Student = require('../models/Student');

function destroy(req, res) {
  var params = req.params;
  var body = req.body;

  Student.findById(params.student_id, function(err, student) {
    student.dishes.id(params.dish_id).remove();
    student.save(function(err) {
      res.redirect('/');
    })
  });
}

module.exports = {
  create: create,
  delete: destroy
}
```

**view (ejs)**

```
<% student.dishes.forEach(function(dish) { %>
    <p><%= dish.dish %></p>
    <p><%= dish.cuisine %></p><br>
    <form action="/<%= student._id %>/dishes/<%= dish._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete This Dish">
    </form>
    <br>
<% }) %>
```

The error I am getting is

```
Not Found
404
NotFoundError: Not Found
```

With a long non-helpful stack trace. When i put some console log statements in the route, i can tell it's not hitting it, but I can't tell why. I made a similar app and it worked, so i can't tell what's wrong with this one.

Does anyone see a mistake I am making, or is there something I need to add that isn't there? I can post more code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

router.route('/:student_id/dishes/:dish_id').get(DishesController.delete);

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure if `router.route` is valid. i changed to it and it didn't change anything